# errors in copy method

Tags: java, copy

> i'm relatively new on this site as well as the world of programming, so hi. my code is throwing a stack overflow error, and i can't seem to figure out why and how to fix it.

```
public static retailitem copy()
        {
            retailitem ItemX = new retailitem("Sweatpants", 23, 25.50);
            retailitem ItemY;
            ItemY = ItemX.copy(// This is where the error occurs

            System.out.println("Item X: \n" + ItemX);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Item Y: \n" + ItemY);

            if (ItemX == ItemY)
                System.out.println("Variables ItemX and ItemY" +
                                    "reference the same object.");
            else
                System.out.println("Variables ItemX and ItemY" +
                                    "reference different objects.");

            return ItemY;
        }
```

Comment: Please add the error stacktrace

Comment: Your `copy` method is calling itself, basically - assuming that the method you've shown us is in `retailitem`. Aside from anything else, I would strongly recommend: a) not using static methods as if they were instance methods (e.g. `ItemX.copy`); b) learning about and following Java naming conventions; c) always using braces even for single-statement-bodied `if` statements.

Comment: You should provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), what you have shown does not even compile. Other than that, what Jon Skeet said, you have endless recursion.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive calls to the copy method are causing an exception in your code, and there is no exit or stop condition to end the recursion in the copy method.

However, To copy an object in Java you need to implement the [Cloneable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) interface. The [clone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) method is used to make a field for field copy of instances of any class.

Please refer to the below code sample for more details.

```
class retailitem implements Cloneable
{
    private String item;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;

    public retailitem(String item, int quantity, double price)
    {
        this.item = item;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public static retailitem copy()
    {
        retailitem ItemX = new retailitem("Sweatpants", 23, 25.50);
        retailitem ItemY;
        ItemY = ItemX.clone(); // This creates and returns a copy of this object. 

        System.out.println("Item X: \n" + ItemX);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Item Y: \n" + ItemY);

        if (ItemX == ItemY)
            System.out.println("Variables ItemX and ItemY" +
                    "reference the same object.");
        else
            System.out.println("Variables ItemX and ItemY" +
                    "reference different objects.");

        return ItemY;
    }

    @Override
    public retailitem clone()
    {
        try
        {
            retailitem retailItem = (retailitem) super.clone();

            retailItem.item = this.item;
            retailItem.quantity = quantity;
            retailItem.price = this.price;

            return retailItem;
        }
        catch (CloneNotSupportedException e)
        {
            throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }
}

public class CloneTesting
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        retailitem.copy();
    }
}
```